# How to fix NoReverseMatch error in Django for the getting and displaying user specific data in ListView

Tags: django

Hey I have a video sharing webapp project with basic CRUD operations in it. Any user after successful login can post any number of videos and after login the user is redirected to home page of another app inside the django project.

Home page shows all the videos uploaded by different users. Now I want place all the videos uploaded by the user at an seprate endpoint. If user clicks on this endpoint link in the nav-bar then the user should be directed to this endpoint containing all the videos uploaded by him/her.

I am using builtin class based view **ListView** for this purpose and I have just one model of **Video**.
But I am getting Noreversematch error after performing get_queryset() function and here is my error :
[image: Endpoint page showing error]
**part of views.py**

```
class UserUploads(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
model = Video
template_name = 'courses/user_uploads.html'
context_object_name = 'videos'


def get_queryset(self):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    return Video.objects.filter(uploader=user).order_by('-date_time')


def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('courses:video-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

**part of urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from .views import CreateVideo, DetailVideo, UpdateVideo, DeleteVideo
app_name = "courses"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Index.as_view(), name = "home"),
    path('user-uploads/<str:username>', views.UserUploads.as_view(), name = "user-uploads"),
    path('create-video',  CreateVideo.as_view(), name='video-create'),
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailVideo.as_view(), name='video-detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/update-video', UpdateVideo.as_view(), name='video-update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete-video', DeleteVideo.as_view(), name='video-delete'),
]
```

**html document of home page nav-bar containg videos of all the different users**

```
{% block content %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="create-video">Create Video</a>
            </li>
            
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'courses:user-uploads' user.username %}">Your Videos</a>
            </li>
            
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/logout">Log-Out</a>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        {% for object in object_list %}
        <div class="card col-md-3 col-sm-12 mr-md-2 mt-5 p-3 border-0">
            <a href="{% url 'courses:video-detail' object.pk %}"><img src="/media/{{ object.thumbnail }}" width="256" height="144"></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <a class="link-text" href="{% url 'courses:video-detail' object.pk %}"><h5 class="text-center">{{ object.caption }}</h5></a>
                <p class="text-muted text-center m-0">{{ object.uploader }}</p>
                <p class="text-muted text-center">{{ object.date_time | date:"M d, Y" }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**courses:user_uploads.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Your Courses {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="create-video">Create Video</a>
            </li>
                        
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/logout">Log-Out</a>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

    <h1>Your Uploads</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            {% for video in videos %}
            <div class="card col-md-3 col-sm-12 mr-md-2 mt-5 p-3 border-0">
                <a href="{% url 'courses:video-detail' video.pk %}"><img src="/media/{{ video.thumbnail }}" width="256" height="144"></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a class="link-text" href="{% url 'courses:video-detail' object.pk %}"><h5 class="text-center">{{ video.caption }}</h5></a>
                    <p class="text-muted text-center m-0">{{ video.uploader }}</p>
                    <p class="text-muted text-center">{{ video.date_time | date:"M d, Y" }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Video(models.Model):
   uploader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   video_description = models.TextField()
   video_file = models.FileField(upload_to="courses/video_files", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp4'])])
   thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to="courses/thumbnails", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])])
   date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.caption
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following code because `video.pk` is an empty string.

```
<a href="{% url 'courses:video-detail' video.pk %}">
```

This can be determined because the error message says the reverse was performed with arguments `('',)` indicating it was passed an empty string for a positional argument.

Does the Video model have a field specified for the primary key or does it use the automatic id field provided by Django? You may want to use that specific field or `.id` if it's using the auto id.

Comment: As you suggested that where it might create problem but you can see my home page html document where the link is : <a href="{% url 'courses:video-detail' object.pk %}"> working fine and it is just creating problem only in user_uploads.html file.

Comment: No Video model doesn't have any specified field for pk.

Comment: @diff Do you have any fields on that model with `primary_key=True`?

Comment: No nothing like that.

Comment: Odd. I'd start by checking to see what `videos` all contains and why the `pk` isn't set.

Comment: Hey I want to add something here that in my models.py file you can see that I have nothing like that. But I am using xampp for MySql and its phpAdmin where it has id field and set as primary and uploader is saved with its id again in implementation of User model the primary field is id. Eg : User1 -> id = 1 username = u1 password = pass1 etc. , User2 -> id = 2 username = u2 password = pass2 etc.

Comment: As long as you don't have `managed = False` set in the model's meta class, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Meta is not sorting out this problem

Comment: Yep, it's something else. Check the queryset being returned and what's being sent to the template. Something has `video.pk == ''`

Comment: Hey if just use the view without declaration of //context_object_name// it works fine without any error.